# How to autologin to wordpress site from another react website using aws cognito?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, woocommerce, amazon-cognito, wordpress-rest-api

I have a website made in nextjs using NodeJS backend . I am using aws Cognito for authentication . I want users from my website to buy the pro feature from WordPress WooCommerce.
We have already implemented the buying feature in WordPress. I just want to autologin to WordPress when a user logs into my website and try to purchase the pro feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Miniorange plugin to login users using cognito and then  provide them the buying option using woocommerce.

https://plugins.miniorange.com/wordpress-oauth-client-setup